# Specify C++ object attributes in a fancy way with no constructor provided

Tags: c++, constructor, c++14

Consider this trivial class:

```
#include <string>
class A
{
public:
    A( int i, const std::string& str ) : i(i), str(str)
    {
    }

    inline int getValue() const { return i; }
    inline std::string getName() const { return str; }

private:
    int i;
    std::string str;
};

int main()
{
    A a(3,"dkd");
    //...
    return 0;
}
```

It's "a pain" to have to maintain the constructor when new attributes are added to the class. OK, not that painful, but when the constructor is so obvious (it gets the parameters of the same type than attributes and in the same order), it would be nice not to have to declare any, and have a default one provided that would simply work!

I was thinking of something like:

```
#include <string>
class A
{
public:
    inline int getValue() const { return i; }
    inline std::string getName() const { return str; }

private:
    int i;
    std::string str;
};


int main()
{
    A a{ 3, "ff" };
    ///...
    return 0;
}
```

Is this doable in C++?

Comment: In C++, class member functions are `inline` by default, so `inline` key use becomes redundant. 
Your current requirement turns out that you don't need to use `class` but `struct` whose members are public by default instead.
Last by not least, you should read a book, not articles or posts on forums or sites like StackOverflow then self-claim you have experiences with C/C++. These are personal opinions and information shared to keep coders and interested readers updated.

Comment: @TheUnknown: "class member functions are inline by default" Does that mean in C++ all class member function are inline, I doubt that's is true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not for your case. Something exists which allows you to do this, and it's called [aggregate initialisation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization). It can't be used in your example, because it can only be used on classes which

- Have no private/protected non-static members
- Have no constructors
- Have no `virtual` functions

From the link itself:

> Aggregate initialization is a form of list-initialization, which initializes aggregates
>   An aggregate is one of the following types:
>   * array type
>   * class type (typically, struct or union), that has
>   no private or protected non-static data members
>   no user-provided, inherited, or explicit (since C++17) constructors (explicitly defaulted or deleted constructors are allowed) (since C++11)
>   no virtual, private, or protected (since C++17) base classes
>   no virtual member functions
>   no default member initializers

If your class had `public` members instead, you would be able to have the following:

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    std::string str;
};

int main()
{
    A a{ 3, "ff" };
}
```

If you then extend your class by adding a new member to it, you don't need to update old code. Members not included in the initialiser list are default initialised:

> If the number of initializer clauses is less than the number of members or initializer list is completely empty, the remaining members are value-initialized.

```
class A
{
public:
    int i;
    std::string str;
    double d;
};

int main()
{
    A a{ 3, "ff" }; // your old code still works, a.d becomes 0.0
    A b{ 3, "ff", 1.0 };
    A c{}; // 0, "", 0.0
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Do you know what the reason why it does not work with private members? `private` is just a compiler statement, don't understand why the standard makes it prevent this to work....

Comment: @jpo38 In theory, `private` members can only be accesed by member functions (and friends). Constructors could initialize `private` members, but aggregate initialization tries to initialize members directly and the constructor is bypassed, but it can't "access" `private` members.

Comment: @songyuanyao: Got it, but the standard could allow such initialization to set private attributes, the compiler could support that, it knows what private attributes are and how to access those. But I agree it would be wierd, because it would, in the end, let an extenral entity access them...

Comment: @jpo38 Yes, I understand what you mean. And, aggregate initialization is supposed to be applied for "POD" structs from before; so it's not allowed also for the consistency.

Answer (score 1):

Read about http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization, 
your code will not be compiled bacause members of your class are privated.

If members of your class are public, your code will work.